# How to output mp4 after concatenation using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to merge a couple of mp4 videos (with different fps, heigth, width and bitrate).

I tried this with a few videos, but it always hides or skips some video files from the `input.txt`.

How can I correctly merge those mp4 files?

Thank you!

My command:

```
ffmpeg, "-f", "concat", "-i", "concatfile.txt", "-c:v", "copy", "-sn", "-y", "merged_video.mp4", "-max_muxing_queue_size", "1024"
```

-> the video does not play correctly

EDIT:
i now output the information of each video in concat.txt_

```
INPUT1:
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000028cdd7c3d00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter

Input #0, concat, from 'concatfile.txt':

  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 535 kb/s

    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 435 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 05/10/2019.

    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 100 kb/s

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 05/10/2019.

INPUT2:
mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000256592b3d00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter

Input #0, concat, from 'concatfile.txt':

  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 620 kb/s

    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 522 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/31/2018.

    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 97 kb/s

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/31/2018.


INPUT3:
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001a774cd3d00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter

Input #0, concat, from 'concatfile.txt':

  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 609 kb/s

    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 513 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/31/2018.

    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/31/2018.


INPUT4:
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000165b1013c80] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter

Input #0, concat, from 'concatfile.txt':

  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 510 kb/s

    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 415 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/31/2018.

    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/31/2018.

INPUT5:
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001c545493c80] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter

Input #0, concat, from 'concatfile.txt':

  Duration: N/A, start: -0.042667, bitrate: 2972 kb/s

    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 900x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 2862 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : VideoHandler

    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 110 kb/s

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Could be the issue, that the last mp4 has mono audio?

Comment: All inputs must have the same attributes. Either conform the others to match the main content by filtering and re-encoding then use the concat demuxer, or re-encode and concat everything in one command by using the concat filter (there are several Q/A here that show how to do either). If you need more help then [edit] your question to include info on each input listed in `concatfile.txt`, such as by running `ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4` and providing the complete log.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, i´ve updated the question regarding your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

All inputs must have the same attributes, but input #5 is different than the rest: width, height, audio sample rate, and audio channel layout. Conform it to the specs of the others:

```
ffmpeg -i input5.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:360:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v];[0:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" input5b.mp4
```

Now concatenate.